# QuickBooks IdsException in CoreHelper.php line 95

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I'm working with the [QuickBooks v3 PHP SDK 2.3.0](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0209_php/php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3). I used The PHP League's OAuth 1.0 client instead of going about it the SDK's way, because it's much simpler. That shouldn't really matter, though. I successfully authorized my app and saved the credentials.

However when I follow the [examples in the docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0209_php/php_sdk_for_quickbooks_v3/0002_synchronous_calls#/Batch_Process), nothing seems to work properly.

In each example below, I use the following code to get set up:

```
require_once(Path::assemble(
    $this->getDirectory(),
    'vendor/QuickBooks/v3-php-sdk-2.3.0/',
    'config.php'
));
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Core/ServiceContext.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'DataService/DataService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'PlatformService/PlatformService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Utility/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php');

$tokenCredentials = $this->storage->getYAML('quickbooks/token.yaml');
$consumerCredentials = [
    'key'    => $this->getConfig('oauth_consumer_key'),
    'secret' => $this->getConfig('oauth_consumer_secret'),
];

$requestValidator = new \OAuthRequestValidator(
    array_get($tokenCredentials, 'identifier'),
    array_get($tokenCredentials, 'secret'),
    array_get($consumerCredentials, 'key'),
    array_get($consumerCredentials, 'secret')
);

$oauth_response = $this->storage->getYAML('quickbooks/response.yaml');

$realmId        = array_get($oauth_response, 'realmId');
$serviceType    = \IntuitServicesType::QBD;
$serviceContext = new \ServiceContext($realmId, $serviceType, $requestValidator);

$dataService = new \DataService($serviceContext);
```

If I dump and die `$dataService`, I get my `DataService` object. However any query I try to perform returns `null`:

```
$dataService->Query('SELECT * FROM Customer');
$dataService->Query('SELECT count (*) FROM Vendor');
$dataService->FindAll('Customer', 1, 10);
$dataService->Query('SELECT * FROM *');
```

This final example is what throws the `IdsException`:

```
$customerObj              = new \IPPCustomer();
$customerObj->Name        = "Name" . rand();
$customerObj->CompanyName = "CompanyName" . rand();
$customerObj->GivenName   = "GivenName" . rand();
$customerObj->DisplayName = "DisplayName" . rand();

$resultingCustomerObj = $dataService->Add($customerObj);
```

error:

```
/DataService/DataService.php - 463 - CheckNullResponseAndThrowException - Response Null or Empty
```

Comment: I had been checking the logs, but they'd seemed useless until I decided to check again just now. It seems I'm using a Production URL rather than a Sandbox one. I'll report back once I figure more out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I hadn't updated `sdk.config` to use the Sandbox URL.

```
<baseUrl qbd="https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" qbo="https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" ipp="https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/" />
```

Now I'll just have to figure out a way to automatically use the appropriate URL based on the environment…